# Change bullet point color in selected TextFrame

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to change the color of bullet points in PowerPoint.

I found

```
Sub Bullet()

With Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(1).TextFrame

    With .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet
        .Visible = True
        .RelativeSize = 1.25
        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)
    End With

End With
End Sub
```

It changes the mentioned slides of mentioned shape.

I want if I select some TextFrame it should change that selected TextFrame only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `activewindow.selection`. This will apply your code to the selected object only.

```
Sub Bullet()
    With ActiveWindow.Selection
        With .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet
            .Visible = True
            .RelativeSize = 1.25
            .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```